# SharedPreferences not saved using PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to create a very basic preferences activity, extending `PreferenceActivity`. In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html), I read:

> The `PreferenceActivity` automatically persists the settings associated with each `Preference` when the user makes a change.

However, when I:

- Change a setting (*any* setting)
- Close the app
- Remove the app from the recently used list
- Relaunch the app

The setting is reset to the default value, which seems to conflict the quoted documentation above. Do I misunderstand something here, is the template faulty, or do I perhaps need additional permissions or other settings to use the PreferenceActivity auto-persist feature?

```java
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

And `preferences.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference
        android:key="pref_language_reading"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_language_dailyreading"
        android:entries="@array/pref_languages_dailyreading_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_languages_dailyreading_values"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_language_dailyreading_default" 
        android:persistent="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The strings and arrays exist, and I can select a language properly. The setting is saved when I go to another activity, and then back. But closing the app and relaunching discards the saved value.

When I read out the SharedPreference corresponding to this preference (before relaunching), I see the correct setting. After relaunching, the SharedPreference does not exist anymore though.

Comment: it should work, do you have your code online ?

Comment: show only SettingActivity

Comment: it's look too complicated. Is that all generated by AS ? HArd to figureout what's happening there, I think that bindPreferenceSummaryToValue set values back to default/ try to comment it and check. Also I suggest you to create Preferences screen from scratch, it's very simple concept, you just define Preference in xml, bind it to Activity and framework will do all the work to save your data.(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) And your code will be much more cleaner than generated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should work. There is likely something else in your code that causes this behaviour.

In my specific case, it turned out there was a line

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().clear().commit();
```

In the `onCreate()` method of the main `Activity`, causing the SharedPreferences to *clear* on every launch of the app.